# Expressão regular em JavaScript para validar tamanho do nome de usuário

Tags: javascript, regex

Eu preciso de uma expressão regular em JavaScript que atenda às seguintes regras:

- Ter entre 2 e 255 caracteres
- Em caixa baixa (lower case)
- Conter apenas alfanuméricos, underline (_), ponto (.) ou hífen (-).

Comment: dica, este site é muito bom para testar suas regex e tbm permite salvar e compartilha-las. http://www.regexpal.com/

Comment: Precisa permitir caracteres acentuados?

Answer (score 3):

Tente isso para capturar linha exata:

```
/^[a-z0-9_\.-]{2,255}$/
```

Atende às regras:

- Ter entre 2 e 255 caracteres
- Em caixa baixa (lower case)
- Contém apenas alfanuméricos, unerline (_), ponto (.) ou hífen (-).

Answer (score 1):

A regex fica assim:

```
/^[a-z0-9_\.-]{2,255}$/
```

Comment: William, duas pequenas correções: o caractere -(traço) deve ficar no fim da lista, caso contrário será interpretado como intervalo, semelhante à a-z. E se não me engano não é preciso escapar .(ponto) dentro dos colchetes[].

Comment: Boa! fiz de cabeça. Você tem razão, corrigido.

Comment: Precisa escapar o ponto.

Comment: Caracteres especiais (como o ponto (`.`) e o asterisco(`*`)) não tem significado algum quando está dentro de um conjunto de caracteres. Não necessita utiliza escape neles. Mas, se utilizar escape também irá funcionar. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-character-set